# Escaping single quotes in a console log output

Tags: javascript

I am putting custom JavaScript into a GTM container to loop through an array of hyperlinks that I have used .map to create. Then create a JSON output based on the values within it (using a combination of the index number and the href values).

**NOTE: ES6 solutions will not work here as GTM unfortunately does not support it.**

I am having trouble with escaping the single quotation marks:

I want the output to be like this:

```
'id': '1',
'name': 'https://example.com',
'creative': 'store-banner',
'position': 'slot-1'
```

and below is my attempt to print out the array into console log and assign it the appropriate syntax:

```
for (var i = 0; i < carouselArray.length; ++i) {
  console.log("'id':" + '\(i+1)'\ + ", 'name': " + '\carouselArray[i]'\ + ", 'creative': store-banner, 'position': slot-" + \'(i+1)'\);
}
```

I am trying to get the dynamic values be surrounded by single quotations but I keep getting syntax errors and can not seem to figure out what I am doing wrong. Can someone please help to show me what I am missing or doing incorrect?

Comment: Can you post the actual array you're trying to loop through?

Comment: Remove **all** slashes to resolve your syntax errors -- none of the slashes there are needed. Then, use [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to make your life easier.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @costaparas, but I am doing this in GTM and it does not support ES6 unfortunately.

Comment: @RyanCoolwebs Well, wish you pointed that out earlier.

Comment: @codemonkey, note taken - my bad. I have updated the question to be more clear. All the array contains is a list of URL strings.

Comment: Updated the answer to not use ES6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you can't use ES6, here is an old school way to display your array in the way you want to display it:

```js
const ar = ['https://example.com', 'http://example.net', 'https://example.org'];
for (var i = 0; i < ar.length; ++i) {
  console.log("'id': '"+(i + 1)+"',\n'name': '"+ar[i]+"',\n'creative': 'store-banner',\n'position': 'slot-"+(i + 1)+"'\n--------\n");
}
```

Comment: This is brilliant! Thanks. It is a real shame that GTM only supports a weird custom ES5.1 subset of JS https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/templates/sandboxed-javascript.

Comment: @RyanCoolwebs I am actually surprise to hear that. I mean this is 2021 for God's sake.

Answer (score 0):

```js
     var carouselArray =[{'id': '1',
        'name': 'https://example.com',
        'creative': 'store-banner',
        'position': 'slot-1'}]

        for (var i = 0; i < carouselArray.length; ++i) {
        console.log(`id : ${i+1} \n name : ${carouselArray[i].name} \n creative : ${carouselArray[i].creative} \n position :${carouselArray[i].position} `)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The \ needs to go before the ' but there's no need to escape them as you are surrounding it all with double quotes. If you want to access a variable or something, or the index+1, just type (index+1).

You can also use template literals. Using back ticks you can do:

```
for (var i = 0; i < carouselArray.length; ++i) {
  console.log({
     'id': `${i+1}`,
     'name': `${carouselArray[i].name}`,
     'creative': 'store-banner', // assuming this is a string? Not variable
 'position': `slot-${i+1}`
});
```

Or

```
carouselArray.map((carousel, index) => {
    console.log({
        'id': index+1,
        'name': carousel.name,
        'creative': 'store-banner',
        'position': index+1
    });
});
```